# Is Windows App Runtime backward compatible

Tags: windows-runtime, winui-3, c++-winrt, windows-app-sdk

I am working on a WinUI3 application for the desktop application in cpp. I am trying to build the application as a single executable(.exe). So I chose framework dependant unpackaged mode. When we chose a framework dependant unpackaged mode of development for WinUI3 we should [explicitly install Windows App Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/deploy-unpackaged-apps#overview) in the end user's machine.

I installed the latest Windows App Runtime (version 1.3) on my machine and then tried to run an App that is built for Windows App Runtime (version 1.2), but I got this error saying

[image]

I have the latest Windows app runtime installed

[image]

Does this mean Windows App Runtime is not backward compatible? Or is there any whay to overcome this drawback?

Thank you

Comment: How do you "reference and initialize the Windows App SDK Framework package at runtime"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/deploy-unpackaged-apps#runtime-requirements-for-apps-packaged-with-external-location-or-unpackaged

Comment: Had you already asked on the github repo? https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK

Comment: The Windows App SDK/WinUI 3 is ultimately WPF 2 now: Desktop only, C# only. If you're planning to use it from anything but C#, you're pretty much forced into constantly catching up, figuring out implementation details that caused your program to break, implement a workaround, and start over. And eventually [give up](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-app-rs). *"Project Reunion"* has failed to deliver on its promises and goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can manually use the bootstrapper API REf - https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/3657